# Vue.js How to target object with unknown name in an array on v-model input

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, javascript-objects, v-model

I am generating an object onclick with an automatically-generated name. The name will be different each time. I then want to change the object's values with an input using v-model. How can I target the object if the name is unknown? Here's what I have so far:

```
<ul>
  <li v-for="type in types" @click="addNew(type)">{{ type }}</li>
</ul>

<form v-if="Object.keys(newFields).length !== 0">

  <input type="text" v-model="newFields[0].?????????">

</form>

  <script>
  new Vue ({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
      types: [
        'date',
        'number',
        'currency',
        'text',
      ],
      savedFields: [

      ],
      newFields: [

      ]
    },
    methods: {
      addNew: function (type) {

        const name = `${type}-${Object.keys(this.savedFields).map(key => key === type).length}`;

        if (Object.keys(this.newFields).length == 0) {
          this.newFields = Object.assign({}, this.newFields, {
            [name]: {
              'type': type,
              'displayLabel': '',
              'defaultValue': '',
            }
          });
        }
      },
    },
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the name as a reactive data. For e.g., save it in `currentName`

```
<script>
    new Vue({
        el: "#app",
        data: {
            //...
            currentName: null
        },
        methods: {
            addNew: function (type) {
                const name = ""; //...

                this.currentName = name;

                //...
            }
        }
    });

</script>
```

and for the v-model,

```
<input type="text" v-model="newFields[0][currentName]">
```

Comment: Thanks...I think this is close but now I'm getting the following error:

Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'date-0' of undefined"

How to solve this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @LaurenMastroni I think the reason is that `newFields` is an empty array. `newFields[0]` doesn't exist. Perhaps you can try to set the initial value of `newFields` to `[ {} ]` (an array with only 1 value, which is an empty object), so that `newFields[0]` won't be undefined anymore. I am not sure why you design your data this way though. Hope that this won't affect your app logic.

Comment: I'm not sure why either haha...thanks for your help!